# put checkbox in cells jqgrid plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I using Jqgrid for show my binary data. I want instead showing 0 or 1 in cells show Checkbox which checked if value of cell is 1 and unchecked if 0. how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just add

```js
formatter: "checkbox"
```

in the column definition for the column (in `colModel`).